# What is the difference between preceding and following in teradata query

Tags: sql, teradata

I am confused why we use this min function.I am not able to understand how the below snippet works.Please guide

```
COALESCE( min((start_Date)) OVER (partition by Seq_id  ORDER BY start_Date rows between 1 following and 1 following),cast( '9999-12-31 00:00:00' as timestamp(6))  end_Date FROM table.test1
```

Comment: Teradata is not Oracle.

Answer (score 2):

This is your query:

```
SELECT COALESCE(min((start_Date)) OVER (partition by Seq_id 
                                        ORDER BY start_Date
                                        rows between 1 following and 1 following
                                      ),
         cast( '9999-12-31 00:00:00' as timestamp(6))
        ) as end_Date
FROM table.test1
```

This query is doing;

```
SELECT COALESCE(LEAD(Start_Date) OVER (PARTITION BY seq_id ORDER BY start_date),
                cast( '9999-12-31 00:00:00' as timestamp(6))
               ) as end_Date
```

That is, it is fetching the date value from the "next" row as defined by `Start_Date`.

I think this construct is used because (some versions of) Teradata do not support `LEAD()`.

Comment: Can you please clarify why we use min function inside the coalesce function. What does 1 following and 1 following mean by?

Comment: @RajeswariRanganathan . . . This is a window/analytic function.  You should look up the documentation to see how it gets used.  If you use `preceding` you have the equivalent of `lag()`.

Answer (score 0):

You will find nice explanation with Teradata window function,Rows between Preceding  and Preceding :
http://pauldhip.blogspot.dk/2015/04/window-function-rows-between-preceding.html

Comment: Blog links have a tendency to die and leave answers useless - could you please include the relevant parts in your answer?

Comment: Hi Ben, the blog post exactly explain the header of this post and it has nice explanation to understand easily. But someone need to read two of the post to get it clearly. Please ask me if you don't understand it yet.